# EWS Custom Attribute/Header/Categories

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS (Exchange Web Service) C#.

I want to send an email message with my own id and to read from the message my own id.

What I'm tried (The message send):

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(_service);

email.Subject = "Title"
email.Body = new MessageBody("Message Body.");

//Trying with category                
email.Categories.Add("123456");//Test

//Trying with Property 
// Get the GUID for the property set.
Guid MyPropertySetId = new Guid("{C11FF724-AA03-4555-9952-8FA248A11C3E}");

// Create a definition for the extended property.
ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MyPropertySetId, "123324", MapiPropertyType.String);

email.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, "TestTEst");

//Send the mail
email.Send();
```

And after i'm trying to read the email message i cant see the categories/extendproperty, why its happend? I need to "Save" the properties that i'm added?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code your using to read the email ? are you loading the property using a propertySet ?

Comment: @GlenScales, I'm do it as follow: SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, new ItemView(int.MaxValue));
and iterate over the items

Comment: That won't load the property then you need to define a property set add that property to the Set then use the propertyset property on the Item-view object which tells exchange to return that property

Comment: How can i do that? you can give me an example please?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633697(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: @GlenScales, Thanks!